# Bing API HTTP request timeout

Tags: http, bing, bing-api

I'm using Bing V7 API and sending an HTTP requests for this endpoint:

```
https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/search
```

When I'm define my HttpClient, I need to select the right Timeout value. To short timeout, will makes me loose some answers from the server. Too long timeouts, will make me wait, even if the server is not there.

I looked on Bing [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/he-il/rest/api/cognitiveservices/bing-web-api-v7-reference) and didn't find the right value.

What is the right HTTP request timeout for this calls?

Answer (score 2):

> What is the right HTTP request timeout for this calls?
>   I'm using Bing V7 API and sending an HTTP requests for this endpoint:

Bing provides their API via a HTTP endpoint. This has nothing really to do with the API itself in my opinion as HTTP is just the transport in this situation. HTTP request context is normally handled by eg. reverse proxies such as NGINX (or likely MS IIS here). Hence no documentation in the API docs.

> When I'm define my HttpClient, I need to select the right Timeout value. To short timeout, will makes me loose some answers from the server. Too long timeouts, will make me wait, even if the server is not there.

The timeout value in your `HttpClient` is just ment to eventually recover from a `blocking` situation. This means that your program won't block indefinitely, but will at some point terminate the HTTP action at hand. This is useful if your `HttpClient` got into a eg. network split situation, deadlock or similar situation and no reply will ever come.

A timeout value between 45 to 60 seconds is plenty.

> Too long timeouts, will make me wait, even if the server is not there.

I would keep the `HttpClient` timeout value at a fixed eg. 60 seconds and have a second "supervisor" thread doing some more dynamic "Smoke test" to check if connectivity is ok or if there is some other problem at which point you then can terminate `HttpClient` early.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. When you said "A timeout value between 45 to 60 seconds is plenty" - what you based on? I'm sure that Bing should document this specification on their documentation. There's no other way to guess it. In my experience, requests take <10 seconds. But, I don't want to guess it.

Comment: @No1Lives4Ever I base that on my experience when running reverse proxies. You can see eg. here http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_connect_timeout that nginx itself sets 60 seconds as a connect time out as default value. There is no rule for this or known "thats the answer" really.

Comment: Alibaba tengine which drives huge traffic in China also has 60 seconds as a value in their tests. https://github.com/alibaba/tengine/blob/master/tests/test-nginx/cases/lua-tests/023-rewrite/tcp-socket-timeout.t So YMMV.